# Redirect with htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with a redirect with `htaccess`.
I need to redirect 3 different path to 3 different pages where I have static pages if the user is a crawler.

Example:

- www.example.com -> www.example.com/static/index.php
- www.example.com/news -> www.example.com/static/news.php
- www.example.com/home -> www.example.com/static/home.php

I tried the following configuration, but I think there are some rules in conflict, in fact I'm still redirected to prerender service.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^static - [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|crawl|slurp|spider|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home$
    # Proxy the request     
    RewriteRule ^/home /static/home.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|crawl|slurp|spider|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news$
    # Proxy the request     
    RewriteRule ^/news /static/news.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|crawl|slurp|spider|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    # Proxy the request     
    RewriteRule ^/$ /static/index.php [L]

    # Handle Prerender.io
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "------------------"
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Proxy the request
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [L]


    # (REQUEST_FILENAME is only relative in virtualhost context, so not usable)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    # Go to it as is
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If path ends with / and is not just a single /, redirect to without the trailing /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,QSA,L]

    # Accept everything on index.html
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I changed my user agent correctly with google chrome, but I'm still redirected to prerender service.

Comment: Remove leading slashes from the patterns, for example `RewriteRule ^home /static/home.php [L]`

Comment: ...in per-directory .htaccess files, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the URL-path less the directory-prefix (of where the .htaccess file is located) - so it never starts with a slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|crawl|slurp|spider|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC]
# Proxy the request     
RewriteRule ^(home|news)(/.*)?$ /static/$1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|crawl|slurp|spider|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC,OR]
# Proxy the request     
RewriteRule ^/?$ /static/index.php [L]

# If path ends with / and is not just a single /, redirect to without the trailing /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

# Handle Prerender.io
RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "------------------"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|bingbot|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|applebot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
# Proxy the request
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpe?g|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpe?g||tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [L]

# (REQUEST_FILENAME is only relative in virtualhost context, so not usable)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
# Go to it as is
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Accept everything on index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```